# Initializing Objects to null or new?

Tags: java, performance, coding-style

I'm developing a web app and a question arose when I receive parameters on server-side. I initialize my DTO's *(Data Transfer Object)* as local variables to `null` and when a specific parameter is passed, I initialize my object to `new`. An example to illustrate my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Object_DTO object_DTO = null;

    if(request.getParameter("parameter").equals("hello")) {
        object_DTO = new Object_DTO();
        object_DTO.setAttr("attr");
        ...
    }
}
```

My question regarding performance is: what's the best way to initialize objects? Should I set it to `new` on declaration or keep the manner I'm doing?

Comment: Hi, if you are using DTO object inside doPost even if the atribute is not required better to set using new while declaring otherwise whatever u r doing is right...

Comment: Can you provide more a more complete code? Because I don't see reason why not initialize DTO inside if. Also by code-conventions in Java used CamelCase for naming.

Comment: `Camel-casing` will be a good idea too..

Comment: You guys mean "Camel-Casing" like: `ObjectDto` instead of `Object_DTO` ?

Comment: You should worry about clarity first. Assigning to `= null` is likely to be less than 1 nano-second (or optimised away completely), trivial compare to anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally believe it depends on scope. Is `object_DTO` used outside that `if` statement? In this code example, it might be useful to use `null`.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Note that unless except in certain cases (IoC)
    // this scenario is quite easy to avoid
    Object_DTO object_DTO = null;

    if(request.getParameter("parameter").equals("hello")) {
        object_DTO = new Object_DTO();
        object_DTO.setAttr("attr");
        ...
    } else if (request.getParameter("parameter").equals("goodbye")) {
        object_DTO = new Object_DTO();
    }

    if (object_DTO == null) {
        // Bad response
    }
}
```

Otherwise, always try to use the **most limited scope** for a variable, but performance-wise this is minor.

On a seperate performance note, however, I would stop calling `getParameter()` repeatedly. Assign it to a String and refer to that instead:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String parameter = request.getParameter("parameter");

    if (parameter.equals("hello")) {
        Object_DTO = new Object_DTO();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example you should initialize your object before any if statement and change the last if to else block. It's because we shouldn't repeat ourselves. Imagine that after creating object you have to set 5 different fields exactly the same for every if and add 1 different set method for every if - that would be ugly.

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I needed to know. Actually, I'm assigning it to a String, that was just a simple example :). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Object_DTO object_DTO = null;` does not create any object.

`new Object_DTO()` creates and initializes an object, which you should do only when you actually need an object.